# How do I obtain rte_pci_device details from rte_device in dpdk 18.08

Tags: c, dpdk

I want to compare the detected device information ( dev_info of type  struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info )  associated with each port  with configured pci device address details ( of type struct rte_pci_addr  pciaddr).

```
 for (port = 0; port < nb_sys_ports; port++) {
       rte_eth_dev_info_get(port, &dev_info);                                                         
 }
```

But  In struct struct rte_eth_dev_info, field rte_pci_device *pci_dev has been replaced with field struct rte_device *device.
So how do I obtain the rte_pci_device details from rte_device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DPDK supports now non-PCI buses, so it's a bit more complicated. But still, there are few examples. Here is a snippet from the [Ethtool](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/ethtool.html):

```
struct rte_pci_device *pci_dev;

rte_eth_dev_info_get(port_id, &dev_info);

if (dev_info.device)
    bus = rte_bus_find_by_device(dev_info.device);
if (bus && !strcmp(bus->name, "pci")) {
    pci_dev = RTE_DEV_TO_PCI(dev_info.device);
    snprintf(drvinfo->bus_info, sizeof(drvinfo->bus_info),
        "%04x:%02x:%02x.%x",
        pci_dev->addr.domain, pci_dev->addr.bus,
        pci_dev->addr.devid, pci_dev->addr.function);
}
```

Basically, we get the bus of the DPDK port. If it's a PCI, it's safe to use `RTE_DEV_TO_PCI()` macro. The macro returns a pointer to `struct rte_pci_device`, which has the PCI address.